# Custom font size for Text in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, fonts, swiftui

I have a label in my view that I want to use the system font size in medium, with a size of 21 points.
I created a custom extension to re-use the font created:

```
extension Font {
    static var primaryButton: Font {
        return Font.custom("SFUIDisplay-Light", size: 21)
    }
}
```

However, this does not have any effect. I changed the string to `HelveticaNeue-UltraLight` and it did work, so I'm guessing that `SFUIDisplay-Light` is simply the incorrect font name.
In font book, it says `SFProText-Light`, but that also did not work for me.

What is the correct font name of the San Francisco font in SwiftUI?
Or: how can I set the font size using the system font?

Answer (score 272, accepted):

You can set an explicit size for the system font with:

```
.font(.system(size: 60))
```

Comment: But what is the issue with his code? What if he wants to use something other than the system font?

Comment: let view = { ... } ; return condition ? view.font(.system(size: 60)) : view.font(.custom("CUSTOM_FONT_NAME", size: 60))

Answer (score 41):

You can set custom font size like this,

```
.font(.custom("FONT_NAME", size: 20))
```

Comment: I tried Font.custom("SFProText-Bold", size: 16) which is not working

Comment: @EkambaramE Make sure you give the Font Name properly, not Font file name.

Comment: @KannanPrasad is "SFProText-Bold" the wrong font name?

Comment: Careful with custom font names.  I had a MacOS UIKit app that used a font that (unknown to me) was installed by Microsoft Office rather than default with MacOS.  Worked fine on my Mac but my text field showed blank on other Macs without the specific font installed.

Answer (score 39):

```
Text("Default font design").font(Font.system(size:30, design: .default))
Text("Monospaced font design").font(Font.system(size:30, design: .monospaced))
Text("Rounded font design").font(Font.system(size:30, design: .rounded))
Text("Serif font design").font(Font.system(size:30, design: .serif))

Text("Large Title").font(.largeTitle)
Text("Title").font(.title)
Text("Headline").font(.headline)
Text("SubHeadline").font(.subheadline)
Text("Body").font(.body)
Text("Callout").font(.callout)
Text("Caption").font(.caption)
Text("FootNote").font(.footnote)

Text("Custom font").font(Font.custom("OpenSans-Bold", size: 12.3))
```

more detail Please follow: 
https://github.com/arjun011/SwiftUI-Controls

Answer (score 15):

If you want to set a custom font for your text let's say Helvetica Neue then in that case you can do something like this

```
Text("Hello World")
.font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 20))
```

If you just want to go with system font then in that case you can do something like this

```
Text("Hello World")
.font(.system(size: 20, weight: .light, design: .default))
```

Answer (score 8):

```
// Using system font "San Francisco"
let fontSystem = Font.system(size: 13.0)

// Using installed custom font
let fontCustom = Font.custom("YOUR FONT NAME", size: 13.0)
```

You can place the `font*` constant to where you need to set the font style.

Read more from "Getting System Fonts" section in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/font

Answer (score 4):

If you are like me searching for an option to add a system font with specific size, that also scales for Dynamic Type:

```swift
//Usage:
Text("Hello World").systemFont(size: 8.0, relativeTo: .caption, weight: .semibold)

extension View {
    func systemFont(size: CGFloat, relativeTo textStyle: Font.TextStyle, weight: Font.Weight = .regular) -> some View {
        modifier(SystemText(size: size, relativeTo: textStyle, weight: weight))
    }
}
struct SystemText: ViewModifier {
    @ScaledMetric var fontSize: CGFloat
    private let weight: Font.Weight

    init(size: CGFloat, relativeTo textStyle: Font.TextStyle, weight: Font.Weight = .regular) {
        _fontSize = ScaledMetric(wrappedValue: size, relativeTo: textStyle)
        self.weight = weight
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.font(.system(size: fontSize).weight(weight))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
HStack {
 Text("hello world")
  .customFont(AppFonts.WorkSansSemiBold())
   .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
 }
```

and the magic is here

```
import SwiftUI

public enum AppFonts {
    case WorkSansSemiBold(size: CGFloat = 20)
    case WorkSansMedium(size: CGFloat = 17)
    case WorkSansBold(size: CGFloat = 34)
    
    var rawValue: Font? {
        switch self {
        case .WorkSansSemiBold(let size):
            return Font.custom("WorkSans-SemiBold", size: size)
        case .WorkSansBold(let size):
            return Font.custom("WorkSans-Bold", size: size)
        case .WorkSansMedium(size: let size):
            return Font.custom("WorkSans-Medium", size: size)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func customFont(_ customFont: AppFonts) -> some View {
        self.font(customFont.rawValue)
    }
}
```

and then when I need a custom size

```
.customFont(AppFonts.WorkSansSemiBold(size: 14))
```

Comment: take a look at "Variable Font", it makes things even simpler, it allows you to use the .fontWeight(.semibold) or else with a single font file.